# Batch, Run a Command after Another Command?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, call, batch-processing

I'm new with this scripting and I made a little program.
As you can see I need to run Bat2.bat after Bat1.bat is closed.
Please help me with this,
I need to know what I am doing wrong here.

```
@echo off
cls
title xxx
:START
if %time%==xx:xx:xx.xx (
call Bat1.bat
call Bat2.bat
)
if NOT %time%==xx:xx:xx.xx goto START
goto END
:END
```

Comment: Where is your closing paranthese?  (besides it's hard to meet a time down to centiseconds; you should use `geq` instead of `==`)

Comment: this should work fine. What unexpected things happen?

Comment: I Don't Know But As Soon As I Replace == with geq And Run It, It Closes Itself When Time Reached.

Comment: Also I Use Bat1.bat to Start Another Batch File And A VBS File (This VBS File Opens a mp3 File Invisible), So What I Need To Do In Bat2.bat Is Taskkill That mp3 and I Want To Start Bat2.bat As Soon As I Closed, Batch File Which Opened In The Bat1.bat.

Comment: There is probably an issue with `bat1.bat`. Either a severe error (syntax error) which causes it to close or an `exit` command. Please show `bat1.bat`, if you can't find the failure yourself.

Comment: I Fixed It.Thanks For Your Help @Stephan